# Bufferoverflow on stack

Tags: c

I was going through the security issues in C. I could not understand the below code of how it corrupts the stack,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int chk_perm(){
        printf("\n Check Perm \n");
        return 2;
}
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
        int fg;
        char filename[16];

        if(argc != 2){
                fprintf(stderr,"Usage : %s filename\n",argv[0]);
                exit(1);
        }

        fg = chk_perm();
        strcpy(filename,argv[1]);
        if(fg == 0xdeadbeef){
                //execute as root or deposit million dollars in bank account
        }
        else{
                //execute as a normal user , deduct $10 from an account
        }

        return 0;
}
```

The argv[1] passed may change the value of fg.
Its said, that corruption will happen, if argv[1] passed is an entire binary that can cause undesired results can be passed as an argument along with return address.

I could not understand , how the strcpy corrupts the stack check_perm such that the value of the fg gets changed.

My assumption about the program,

When program starts executing, It creates a stack for the main function and put its arguments,return address,local variables onto the stack.So int fg will occupy 4 bytes (08567500 loc)of the stack and filename[16] will occupy next 16 bytes(08567504). Even if the filename is overflowing more than 16 bytes it may corrupt if any local variable was present after it.

So how does the fg gets corrupted due to strcpy(filename,argv[1]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If on your architecture the stack grows *downwards* (as is commonly the case), `fg` will occupy memory immediately *after* `filename`. This means that when you write past `filename`, you smash `fg`.

Comment: this is the only answer that correctly takes stack growth direction into account as well

Comment: @NPE : Thanks. I checked the address of fg and filename. fg is placed below the filename. But I have a doubt. when the stack gets loaded, the parameters,return address,local variables gets stored onto the stack in the order. So the local variables fg has to get the highest address than filename. And the array filename grows from lower to higher sddress. Why filename has the highest address than fg.

Comment: @Angus: Maybe whoever wrote the example was talking about a system with downward stack, but the system you tested on uses an upward stack.

Comment: I tried to declare the fg below the declaration of filename. then also fg occupies the lowest address. if I declare above filename also I get fg as lowest address. when the local varibles gets pused onto stack, the first declared variable has to get the highest address than the one below is my understanding

Answer (score 2):

`fg` is on the stack. So is `filename`. When you `strcpy()` something to `filename` that is larger than 16 it will overwrite `fg`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you are writing past the `filename` buffer. When you do, the next item in line on the stack is the `fg` variable, so it will get bytes written to it if the input file name is more than 15 characters long (and then one more byte is included: the zero terminator).

You need to either make `filename` big enough to hold whatever a user might give you for `argv[1]`, or prevent copying too many bytes. But it's best to allocate the space you need in this case:

```
char filename[PATH_MAX+1];
```

If you want to do it dynamically:

```
char *filename;

if ( !(filename = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1))) ) {
    ... (failure leg)
}
```

Limiting the file name length to `16` bytes (actually `15` plus zero terminator) is extremely impractical for the user, especially since they may provide a full path name for the file parameter. Using a function like `strncpy` risks truncating the user's file name and either generating a file open error or, worse, opening the wrong file.

Comment: strncpy() is a bad advice. A _very_ bad advice.

Comment: @joop yes I agree. I wouldn't even use that method myself. I only showed it in practice since others offered it and wanted to make it more "visible". I've removed it.

Comment: why is strncpy() bad advice?

Comment: @TritonMan `strncpy` has it's place in some scenarios, but in this context, using `strncpy` would just truncate the user's file name if it's too long. So you'd fail somewhere else (*e.g.*, cannot open file).